# I have a loop where text boxes will generate dynamically. i want to capture the text box value when it changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a loop where text boxes will generate dynamically. i want to capture the text box value when it changed.

For each text box having unique "id" value. Can u please help me how to capture text box value
using JavaScript or jquery.

Ex:

```
<!-- here id will generate dynamically -->
<input type="text" id="text1" value="test"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "capture"? What do you want to do with the value at the moment when it is changed?

Comment: just i want  to display that value in alert box.

Answer (score 0):

if your text box has an id say `"myfield"` then you may get the value of that text field by

```
$('#myfield').val();
```

Comment: Here id will generate dynamically, we don't know what is id value that a text box having..

Comment: Please do be sure you specify your problem correctly in your question too..:)

Comment: could you please specify how your id is being generated dynamically...??like text1,text2 etc..???are you appending the counter value to the id..???

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an event handler to capture when the value of that text field has changed. You will need to use jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with the event being `change`. Since the field IDs will be dynamic you can watch all of the inputs (which can be refined to watch only certain ones) and then after the event has fired figure out which one it is. You will use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the input's new value and [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the id (or name).

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('change', function(e) {
    alert($(this).val());
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```